# Windows 8.1 hibernate no longer works after switching to SSD

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, hibernate

My Windows 8.1 PC used to hibernate fine when my HDD was the only disk, but now after switching and migrating to a SSD, the PC hibernates, but instead of resuming on power-on, it boots regularly to the login screen and Windows starts just like after a regular shutdown. I disabled the hibernate option and enabled it again, the hiberfil.sys gets written correctly (at least the timestamp of the last change refreshes correctly), but no luck.

For the migration from HDD to SSD I used Paragon Migrate OS to SSD that also took care of UEFI bootloader (my system is UEFI-only).

Any ideas?

PS: I know hibernate stresses the SSD, but sometimes it's comfortable to leave things open and turn off the PC and then resume where I left.

Comment: I also tried to let Windows fix startup problems, but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure laptop is not encountering a problem with Resume from hibernation and reboots?

If you are, then issue may be that it doesn't hibernate properly despite all signs to the contrary.

There are several suggestions:

1. Make sure your drivers are up to date.
2. Sometimes disabling fast boot fixes the problem
3. Usually hibernation is disabled by SSD management software (at least Samsung Magician does that), but OTOH you say you have it enabled. But make sure you enable it on all your power management profiles.

And last bit: SSDs can take hibernation... My Samsung after 3 months totalled 4TB of writes. This is a lot, and it will drop (lots of windows reinstalls and such), but let's count 1TB a month - that's 1000 months "guaranteed", but 2000 is easily expected. This translates into... wait for it...

83 years with 1TB/month.

Plenty of write cycles to even quadruple the SSD abuse.

EDIT: and from experience - normal windows power-on is much faster than resuming from hibernation. So I stopped bothering with that. From now on its either shutdown or sleep.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, first of all, I am sure it doesn't reboot. Hibernation isn't on / off on a per-schema basis, it's either on or off for everything. What is per-schema is the duration the PC waits until it automatically hibernates when idle. Also, fast boot is coupled to hibernate so as long as hibernate is off, so is fast boot. Last, I don't have any SSD software installed. I know about the Samsung Magician software, but I didn't install it.

Comment: You're right - about hibernation and schemas. I was thinking on several things at the time and  had apparently some stuff mixed.
Fast boot is required for hybrid shutdown. It's not the same as hibernation and AFAIK they're not linked, and in fact they can interfere with each other because of how fast boot works (shouldn't but you never know).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the whole bootloader was sort of screwed up. Today, I enabled the XMP on my RAM and wanted to run the Windows memory diagnosis. It said it would reboot and start, but it rebooted right back into Windows. I started from the installation DVD, assigned a drive letter to the FAT32 boot partition, removed the BCD store and had Windows rebuild it. Now everything works as expected including hibernate.